# Run multiple TOR relays behind one IPv4 address

Tags: ipv6

I have been tinkering with TOR for some while but now I decided to try and run relays. However I am quite a noob to networking.
My ISP will only give each device an IPv6 address public address for all of them is a single IPv4 address. I am wondering if it is possible to run multiple relays behind that single IPv4 address at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each relay must have an IPv4 address, and you can run up to two relays per IPv4 address. I'm not sure if bridges count toward this limit.

https://community.torproject.org/relay/relays-requirements/#public-ipv4-address